# " No such file or directory" on ERB-Sinatra in Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

i'm doing and app for college in Ruby with Sinatra as frameworks, i'm using erb for templates and in local is everything ok but in heroku gives me that error:

```
No such file or directory - /app/views/index.erb:
```

I'm pretty sick of Heroku, all are problems.

Thanks.

Comment: you might want to add the route where you call index.erb. Does it work locally as expected?

Comment: do you have special production/development settings that might not be called?

Comment: I'm using datamapper but only changes the connection to database not the path or stuff like that.

Comment: By the way, i can't add other files too like require 'models/some.rb', same error.

Comment: well, did you commit these files to your repo? Stupid question but anyway.

Comment: Yes sir. Its all updated.

Comment: well, doesn't sound too good then.

Comment: I'm worried also about the fact of i can't make a require of a file

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a problem like this, my paths were messed up. In your `config.ru` file or your `.rb` file, above your sinatra code put:

```
set :root, './'
```

This should fix your problem especially because your also having trouble with your `models`.